Почему в VS code текст вставляется с какими-то переносом на другу строку?

Хотя на исходнике  таких переносов нет. Почему так происходит, как сделать что бы этого не происходило и может быть есть какое то расширение которое это исправит. Конечно отображается в браузере нормально, но просто раздражает.

Отключите Word Wrap клавиши ALT+Z или меню View -> Word Wrap
